# Maximal Element of a subset

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, number-theory

This has probably been asked before but how do I show that every non-empty bounded above subset of $\mathbb N$ has a maximal element? Doesn't the set: $S =[0,1) $ disprove this as I can always pick a larger natural number within $S$ that is not the maximal element? Moreover the supremum $1 \notin S$.

Comment: The set $S$ you created is **not** a subset of $\Bbb{N}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only natural number in $S$ is $0,$ so that does not disprove it.

A set $S \subset\mathbb{N}$ can be seen as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. So, since it is bounded above it will have a supremum in $\mathbb{R}$. Now, you need to prove that this supremum $s$ will be an element of $\mathbb{N}$. You can prove this by contradiction, assuming that it was not and choosing $\frac{s-\lfloor s \rfloor}{2}$ as $\varepsilon.$ We would have to have $x\in S$ such that $\lfloor s \rfloor<\frac{s+\lfloor s \rfloor}{2}<x\leq s$ which is impossible since $x\in \mathbb{N}$.

Then, you use the fact there has to be an element $x\in S$ such that  $s-\frac{1}{2}<x\leq s$. Since $x\in \mathbb{N}$ and $s\in \mathbb{N}$ we must have $x=s$. Hence, $s\in S$ and the set $S$ has a maximum.

Comment: Thank you so much, somehow I'm struggled seeing how a set in the natural numbers could be bounded but I forgot that N is is a subset of R, thank you.

Comment: @Christheyankee Only finite sets can be bounded, an infinite set will always be unbounded above in $\Bbb N$.